# Choreography in qml

Tags: qt, animation, qml

Is there possible to use [choreography](https://material.io/design/motion/choreography.html) animations in qml (in a **REUSABLE** manner)?
for example in StackView transitions from page1 to page2.

I tried following code, but ParentChange does not work as expected. This code just changes red rectangle's position.

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

StackView {
    id: stack
    anchors.fill: parent

    initialItem: Page {
        id: page1
        Label {
            text: qsTr("First page")
            anchors.centerIn: parent
        }

        Rectangle {
            id: rect
            width: 50
            height: 50
            x: 600
            y: 100
            color: "red"

            states: [
                State {
                    when: stack.depth > 1
                    ParentChange { target: rect; parent: stack.currentItem; x: 100; y: 100; }
                }
            ]

            transitions: Transition {
                ParentAnimation {
                    NumberAnimation { properties: "x,y"; duration: 1000 }
                }
            }
        }

        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: stack.push(page2)
        }
    }

    Component {
        id: page2
        Page {
            background: Rectangle { color: "yellow"; anchors.fill: parent }
            Label {
                text: qsTr("Second page")
                anchors.centerIn: parent
            }
        }
    }
}

Rectangle {
    id: back
    color: "blue"
    width: 50
    height: 50
    radius: 25

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: stack.pop()
    }
}
}
```

but the usage is not limited to `StackView`. It can be used in many other situations. (just like above link)

Comment: Please clarify your question. Did you try that? Did you face a problem? Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) article before.

Comment: @folibis question updated

Comment: Thanks @Majid Kamali for updating the question. As for me it will be good if you explain what you want to get. Choreography animation from the link looks like a standard animation exactly like QML animation which you get out of the box.

Comment: The main issue is not about animation. It's about reparenting the Item. When user clicks page1, 'rect' does not remain in the screen and does not go to page2

Comment: Looks like [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). What exactly do you want to archive? Why do you even want `rect` will be parent of `Page` or `StackView`?

Comment: Have you taken a look at all the StackView's Transition-properties? https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-stackview.html